# How to regenerate kubeconfig on a freshly setup kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, session, kubeconfig

I setup a kubernetes cluster using this tutorial 2 days ago - https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-22-04.

The setup went fine, and I could run kubectl commands, create deployments, etc. However when I login now, 2 days later and try to execute any kubectl command, I get:

```
# k get nodes
E0227 09:45:08.352822  125806 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://foo.bar.com:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp w.x.y.z:6443: connect: connection refused
E0227 09:45:08.353636  125806 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://foo.bar.com:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp w.x.y.z:6443: connect: connection refused
E0227 09:45:08.355251  125806 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://foo.bar.com:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp w.x.y.z:6443: connect: connection refused
E0227 09:45:08.356948  125806 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://foo.bar.com:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp w.x.y.z:6443: connect: connection refused
E0227 09:45:08.358446  125806 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://foo.bar.com:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp w.x.y.z:6443: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server foo.bar.com:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Did the kubeconfig expire, or did the api-server creash? How can I check and debug this?

Comment: Did you try exporting the `KUBECONFIG` again?

Comment: I did, did not help!

Comment: does `crictl ps -a | grep api` give you anything? If you see the container, check the apiserver logs using `crictl logs <container-id>`

Comment: Tried that too, any crictl command gives me:
`WARN[0000] runtime connect using default endpoints: [unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock unix:///run/crio/crio.sock unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock]. As the default settings are now deprecated, you should set the endpoint instead.
FATA[0000] listing containers: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/run/dockershim.sock: connect: no such file or directory"`

Answer (score 0):

From your error, we don't see any authentication issue. However, your error message mentions the Kubernetes API server is refusing your connection.

First thing I would check: does `foo.bar.com` (from your error: `foo.bar.com:6443`) resolve to your control plane node? No issues with your DNSes? You didn't add some loadbalancer? If yes => check that one first: is service started, are backends healthy, ...?

Then, as suggested by @Sibtain in comments, the next step would be to check the container that runs that service. There should be some `kube-apiserver`, showing in `crictl ps -a`. Locate the last-started (first-listed) container matching that name and check its logs. This might help you figure out why it's currently down.

You could also check for the `kubelet` service (`systemctl status kubelet`, `journalctl -fu kubelet`), as it is the one that would be tasked to start and restart the kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager & kube-scheduler services, should anything happend.

You may check for the `etcd` service as well. As from kube-apiserver perspective, the only hard dependency is its etcd database. According to one of linuxtechi's screenshot, your etcd should run as a container as well: same as kube-apiserver, `crictl ps -a`, `crictl logs`, make sure container is still running.

---

And answering the title of your post, to generate a new kubeconfig, you may use:

```
kubeadm kubeconfig user --client-name kubernetes-admin \
   --config=/etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml \
   --org system:masters >/path/to/.kube/config
```

Still you probably don't need this: so far, nothing from your post suggests something could be wrong here.

Feel free to edit your post including more logs & errors, depending what you find checking the above.

Comment: I found the issue, somehow the swap got turned back on. When I ran swapoff, it started working again :(. No clue what happened.